# How do I draw a circle in a location in my video

Tags: video

I'm new to Blender and am looking for guidance on how to do a simple task for a research study that I will be running.

Basically, I have a short video (<5 seconds long) of a dog barking. I wish to insert a small, flashing white dot (appears for 500ms) onto the video as a location and time that I choose. (This sounds random, but it's important.)

Could someone please talk me through the steps to do this? Or point me to a tutorial about something similar?

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you try compositing? BTW, this site is for **specific questions**, not detailed explanations of an entire process.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise This sounds like a pretty reasonable question to me..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In blender's VSE we don't have exact control of timing, we can only align to a frame. To get a timing of half a second you will want to use an even number of frames, at 24 fps 12 frames will be 500ms.

To get the dot in place you want an image of the dot, save it as a png so you have the alpha channel to easily clear out everything but the dot. In the VSE add the image, ensure it is above your video, then in the strip properties <kbd>N</kbd> set the blend type to Alpha Over and set the frame length what you want.

[image]

To position the spot, under strip input, enable Image Offset and change the X and Y values until it is in place. You could also create an image the same resolution as your video and place the dot where you want it.

[image]

Then smile as you see the dot on your video.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a mask set as a modifier on a color effect strip. That would eliminate the image creation step and add flexibility to your shape and it's color.